# getting https encrypted data passed over http

Tags: tomcat, https, tomcat7

I'm trying to configure tomcat to work https port 8443.

using tomcat 7.

I enabled the https connectors with the following parameters:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" keystorePass="<pass>"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/foo/bar.keystore"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I created a keystore with the password and the domain required.

when I start tomcat and browse for the admin panel or for my jsp page using port 8443 i get scrumbled unidentified data. which means that i get https encrypted data passed over http.  when i browse on port 8080 i see it properly. what am I missing ?

thank you!

kfir

## update

I have this configuration in server.xml

```
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
```

and I have this in the log:

```
May 02, 2013 5:57:45 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/package
```

so maybe this is the problem.

it's just an INFO so I ignored it. but maybe because of missing APR the SSLEngine is not working.

I have gentoo linux and I have the APR package installed I have no idea why it doesn't detect it.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your logs?

Comment: no errors in my log file

Comment: Are the Certificates self signed? Does the browser give any indication that the connection is https?

Comment: the cert is self signed and the browser doesn't give any indication that it's https

Comment: Maybe show what you are getting - i.e. define "scrumbled unidentified data".

Comment: If you are using self signed certificates, are you generating a keystore, or do you have .pem files?

Comment: @ETL he's getting https encrypted data passed over http.

Comment: i don't have pem files. i have only a keystore file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have misconfigured anything.  However, you may need to explicitly specify the protocol in your URL as well as the port, eg. `https://your.server:8443`.  Most applications (browsers etc.) will infer HTTP if the port isn't 443 and HTTPS isn't specified.

Try also explicitly specifying `http://` in the URL in your browser, just to see if it renders.  I would be surprised, though; it looks like you've enabled TLS correctly.

The lack of the tomcat native library is not the cause.

Comment: Not the port, but the protocol.  I'm sure you got the port.

Comment: ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooops

Comment: ahahahahahahahahahahahahah thank you so much! oh my god i would have spent so many hours on this

Comment: No problem.  It's a really common mistake; I do it a lot too.

Comment: you make my week :) thanks again! have a great day!